# How to change entity name in flash message

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

After editing an object I got this flash message

> L'élément "P\BOBundle\Entity\Distributeur:0000000037396bc6000000006e8ad34e" a été mis à jour avec succès.

So I need to change the entity name in this message: `P\BOBundle\Entity\Distributeur:0000000037396bc6000000006e8ad34e` to  `Distributeur`.

Comment: Flash message content are done via `$this->addFlash('success', 'my flash message');` Why can't you find where you are adding it and edit it?

Comment: thanks for the fast response, the best solution is to override __toString methode in the entity class and make it return the name of object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best solution is to override

> __toString

methode in the entity class and make it return the name of object.

Answer (score -1):

What about using a regex ?

something like :

`\\(\w+):`

http://www.regexr.com/3ef0h

It would be nice to have the code that create that flash message.
Thank you.